# Can Full Calendar create a muli-day event as separate events(pieces of the event) per day

Tags: php, fullcalendar

I am new to full calendar, so I'm really unsure of where to break in to the code for my issue.

First, Full Calendar is great, wow what a time saver, great piece of work! 
Second, I am using a modified version from Paul the Dutchman:
Downloaded here: http://www.paulthedutchman.nl/portfolio/?mi=113

I need to see multi-day events as multiple events on those days rather than the default, in the the Week view, where multi-day events span the height of the columns for the days the event is set for.

Best to think of it like this. A 3 day job is 3 work shifts with different details.(..but really three events to Full Calender)

MON: 1 of 3 | TUE: 2 of 3 | WED: 3 of 3

- I don't need the ID to persist for the event "pieces", they are really separate events.
- I'm only trying to help the user set up the multiple work shifts at the time they create the new event
- Why? = The user may have three consecutive work days..but then one shift/team gets moved, that's why the default event behavior (and separate IDs) is the best solution

I imagined something simple in the Server Side code for the addEvent function that would:

1. check the start end date, subtract the difference
2. php "while" $i <= date diff - create separate events, with only the name being passed

   ```
   $ck_str= date("d",$frm_submitted['date_start'] );
   $ck_end= date("d",$frm_submitted['date_end'] ); <br/>

   if( $ck_str != $ck_end){ // are the day the same? if not do this

   $ck_diff = $ck_end - $ck_str; // subtract days  for events needed
    $i = 1;
   while ($i <= $ck_diff) {
   // add event or modify array if already inside the add function
   // customize the name "Day1: Job Name"

   }}
   ```

The End result, multi events on create with same name

Can it be that simple?

Here is the addEvent Function from Pauls Modified Calendar:

```
function addEvent() {

global $error;

$arr_submit         = array(
    array('cal_id',         'int',          false,  ''),
    array('color',          'varchar',      false,  ''),
    array('date_end',       'int',          false,  ''),
    array('date_start',     'int',          false,  ''),
    array('title',          'varchar',      false,  ''),
    array('location',       'varchar',      false,  ''),
    array('description',    'varchar',      false,  ''),
    array('cal_type',       'varchar',      false,  ''),
    array('interval',       'varchar',      false,  ''),
    array('weekdays',       'varchar',      false,  ''),
    array('monthday',       'varchar',      false,  ''),
);

$frm_submitted      = validate_var($arr_submit);
    $frm_submitted['title'] = stripslashes($frm_submitted['title']);
    $frm_submitted['cal_id'] = 1;  // for this test there is only one calendar

// time offset
$frm_submitted['date_start'] -= TIME_OFFSET;
if(empty($frm_submitted['date_end'])) {
    $frm_submitted['date_end'] = $frm_submitted['date_start'];
} else {
    $frm_submitted['date_end'] -= TIME_OFFSET;
}
if($frm_submitted['title'] == 'undefined') {
    echo json_encode(array('success'=>false));exit;
}

//if(USE_CALENDAR_COLOR_FOR_EVENT) {
if(empty($frm_submitted['color']) || $frm_submitted['color'] == 'undefined') {
    $frm_submitted['color'] = Calendar::getColor($frm_submitted['cal_id']);
}
//}
if(empty($error)) {

    // check if repeating event
    if(isset($frm_submitted['interval']) && ($frm_submitted['interval'] == 'W' ||
                $frm_submitted['interval'] == '2W' ||
                $frm_submitted['interval'] == 'M' ||
                $frm_submitted['interval'] == 'Y')) {
        // weekday

        $arr_days = Utils::getDaysInPattern($frm_submitted);
        $arr_event = Events::insertRepeatingEvent($arr_days, $frm_submitted);

        echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));exit;
    } else {
        // check if this calendar allows overlapping
        //if(!CalendarOwners::allowOverlapping($frm_submitted['cal_id'])) {
            if(Events::isTimeAvailable($frm_submitted) || $frm_submitted['date_end'] != $frm_submitted['date_start']) {
                $arr_event = Events::insertEvent($frm_submitted);
                echo json_encode(array('success'=>true, 'event'=>$arr_event ));exit;
            } else {
                echo json_encode(array('success'=>false, 'error'=>'Overlapping'));exit;
            }
        //} else {
            //$arr_event = Events::insertEvent($frm_submitted);
            //echo json_encode(array('success'=>true, 'event'=>$arr_event   ));exit;
        //}
    }
}
echo json_encode(array('success'=>false));exit;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to replicate some form of event recurrence? i.e. users can may an event recur on a periodic basis and then individually change the characteristics of the individual events as needed?

Comment: I think the request in is most simple form is...that I want the user to create 1 event, but when it runs it splits in to days  with same name.  I guess IT COULD be like recurring but for consecutive days instead of weeks or months??? ...what would that entail to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar need for event recurrence and built my own logic on top of what Full Calendar provided. On the user interface, when the user is adding a new event, I allowed them to specify if they would like the event to be a recurring event. If yes, then I gave them options like "Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly", etc. If they picked "Daily", I would ask, "For how many days?"

I will describe what I did in PHP/pseudo-code because everyone has their unique implementation of such a feature.

Then, I would add the original event as usual. If, `event_recurring = TRUE`, then:

```
$appointment_start; // The original start time of the original event
$appointment_end; // The original end time of the original event
$max_recurence; // The number of days the user wants to recur

if ($max_recurence <  $today) // Skip
else {
   // If frequency == DAILY , other options can be weekly, monthly

   $event_recur_counter = $original_event_start + 1;
   while ($event_recur_counter < $max_recurence){

      $appointment_start = $appointment_start + 1;
      $appointment_end = $appointment_end + 1;

      //Insert the new event (everything else apart from start and end time is the same

      $event_recur_counter = $original_event_start + 1;


}
```

Like I said, there are several ways of doing such a thing but this is the basic idea. You will have multiple events where the only thing that is different between them is their start and end time. From there on in, you can edit some stuff individually for each event without affecting any of the other ones.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this is a great solution, I hadn't thought about recurring daily til..so funny how we focus on some items and miss things like this...I really appreciate it!

Comment: Do you have you version posted somewhere for review, again I'm new to FullCal so its hard for me to "connect the dots" just yet.. in either case ..thanks again!

Comment: I have built a whole bunch of extensions to FullCalendar but never really published them

Comment: Check it out here: http://ventus.sass.uottawa.ca/ . Look for the "Calendar" option at the bottom.